# django input type date receber data do banco de dados

Tags: html, python, django

Estou tentando receber do BD datas e poder editar e salvar mas não consigo puxar as datas para edição no input type="date"

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='expenses'),
    path('add_expense/', views.add_expense, name='add_expense'),
    path('expense_edit/<int:id>', views.expense_edit, name='expense_edit'),
    path('expense_delete/<int:id>', views.expense_delete, name='expense_delete'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.

class Expense(models.Model):
    
    amount = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date'] # - decrecescent desciding
    
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta: # changing Categorys to Categories
        verbose_name_plural =  'Categories'
```

HTML

```
{% block content %}

<h1>Add Expense</h1>
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'expenses' %}">Expenses</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Edit Expense</li>
                </ol>
            </nav>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <!-- {% url 'expense_delete' expense.id %} -->
            <a href="{% url 'expense_delete' expense.id %}" 
            class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                Delete
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>     
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'expense_edit' expense.id %}" class="">{% csrf_token %}
                    {% include 'partials/_messages.html' %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Amount</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
                        name="amount" value="{{ values.amount }}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                        name="description" value="{{ values.description }}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Category</label>                        
                        <select class="form-control" name="category" > 
                            <option selected value="{{ values.category }}">
                                {{ values.category }}
                            </option>                          
                            {% for category in categories %}
                                <option value="{{ category.name }}">
                                    {{ category.name }}
                                </option>                           
                            {% endfor  %}                           
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Date of Expense</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control 
                        form-control-sm" name="expense_date" value="{{ values.date|date:'d/m/Y' }}" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary-sm">
                </form>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Os outros campos consigo puxar do BD menos o de data.

Comment: de acordo com o padrão **Django** tudo esta correto, mas na prática não é seguido o padrão **standart** exemplo do que estou descrevendo em `date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)`  é retornado a `data e a hora` mas creio que não precise das horas. e no **HTML** esta usando `d/m/Y` mas o **Django**  esta retorna lhe `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: um das soluções é formatar a data criando um função dentro da `Expense` def data_formatada(self): return self.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`  pode resolver e pelo **HTML** depois é so usar a  instância do modelo Expense `value="{{ expense.data_formatada|default:'' }}"` no lugar de  `value="{{ values.date|date:'d/m/Y' }}"`

Comment: Não especificou o `TIME_ZONE` para pt-br no settings acho, nao tenho certeza mas poderia ajudar.

Comment: Gratidão, vou ver isso que recomendou

Answer (score 0):

Consegui desta forma, espero que ajude às outras pessoas que é o real propósito do site:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control 
                        form-control-sm" name="expense_date" value="{{ values.date|date:'Y-m-d'  }}" />
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).